# Compile SDL in Cygwin using g++

Tags: c++, compilation, g++, cygwin, sdl

So for school I made a simple game using the SDL graphics library, and did it in Visual Studios C++. However, I must turn in the source code so that it will compile through Cygwin. I have tried so very hard to figure out the proper way to link everything, but just cannot do it.

Normally I would compile a normal .cpp file through Cygwin something like this:

```
g++ -W -Wall -pedantic -o test test.cpp
```

So my questions are:

What is the proper command line command in order to compile (with g++) SDL source code.

Also, how should I folder all the files so that when my instructor gets it, he can run the exact same command as I do?

Should I have the entire SDL library inside with the source code folder? I would like everything grouped so that all he has to do is run the proper command.

The simpler the better :)

Comment: I'd suggest using a makefile or CMake for this. Or just compile SDL as a static library and link to it.